# SELECT totals from previous SELECT using SQL*Plus

Tags: sql, sqlplus

Using SQL*Plus to generate a listing that is e-mailed to a customer, e.g.:

```
SET MARKUP HTML ON
SPOOL spool.html
SELECT order_number, entry_date, delivery_date, customer_order_number, order_totals_quantity, TRUNC(order_totals_sqm,2), order_totals_net_value FROM orders WHERE entry_date = SYSDATE;
```

How can I also create a row that shows the total of the listed `order_totals` fields and keep them in line with those fields?

i.e. if I did a separate `SELECT COUNT()` for those fields it would list them under the first 3 when really they need to be underneath the original `SELECT`.

**Update:** This is what I'm looking for, if it's possible.

```
other columns ... order_totals_quantity | TRUNC(order_totals_sqm,2) | order_totals_net_value
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  Total                 | Total                     | Total
```

Comment: Can you please show the full SELECT statement? Your example is an invalid statement (it's missing the FROM)

Comment: I believe the use of `group by grouping sets` is what you're after but I would need to see expected results example to know how you want to handle it

Comment: I have updated the question with an e.g.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...
Depends on what aggregate you're wanting and what denotes a unique record so as not to sum quantities incorrectly.

```
SELECT order_number, entry_date, delivery_date, customer_order_number, 
  sum(order_totals_quantity), sum(TRUNC(order_totals_sqm,2)), sum(order_totals_net_value)
FROM orders 
WHERE entry_date = SYSDATE;
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((order_number, entry_date, delivery_date, customer_order_number),
         ())
```

Example found: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets.php

Comment: Looking at your link, I wonder if the OP isn't actually after a `GROUP BY ROLLUP`

Comment: I updated the question with an e.g. of what I'm looking for if that helps.

Comment: @user2656114 so does Group By Rollup or group by grouping sets listed above meet your need?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [assuming you are using oracle]:

```
SELECT order_number, entry_date, delivery_date, customer_order_number, order_totals_quantity, TRUNC(order_totals_sqm,2), order_totals_net_value,tot.a, tot.b 
FROM orders, (select sum(order_totals_quantity) a, sum(order_totals_net_value ) b from orders WHERE entry_date = SYSDATE) tot 
WHERE entry_date = SYSDATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using SQL*Plus, there is an easier method using computes.  This has the advantage of no extra SQL running on the server.  Here is an example you can adapt for your query:

```
    BREAK ON report
    COMPUTE SUM LABEL total OF a ON report

    SELECT 1 AS a FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS a FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS a FROM dual;

                A
    -------------
                1
                2
                3
    -------------
                6

    3 rows selected.
```

You can use other aggregates as well.  Here is a link to the full documentation: [COMPUTE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12014.htm).